# SQL Alchemy Execute with List of Dictionaries

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, teradata

Okay,

I've been trying different ways to do this, but basically I am trying to run an ETL job using python, pulling out of Teradata (TD), and uploading the data back in to TD after doing some transformation work. I'm using `Python 3.6` with `sqlalchemy`.

Code is as follows:

```
list_dict = [{'id': '4234l23kjl', 'source': 'Google'},
    {'id': '4s5a6d42', 'source': 'Ad'},
    {'id': '35v469r89', 'source': 'Google'}]
```

I then make a connection to a table using sqlalchemy and get table info for the target table:

```
engine = create_engine(the usual stuff here)

meta = MetaData()

conn = engine.connect()

t = Table('table', meta, autoload=True, 
      autoload_with=engine)

ins = t.insert()
```

I then try and upload in batch by calling:

```
conn.execute(ins, list_dict)
```

To which I get the following issue:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (teradata.api.DatabaseError) (2802, '[23000] 
    [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database] Duplicate row error 
    in db.table. ') [SQL: 'INSERT INTO db.table (source) VALUES (?)'] 
    [parameters: ('Google',)]
```

However, when I print what the `ins` variable I'm creating looks like, it gives the full insert statement I want:

```
INSERT INTO db.table (id, source) VALUES (:id, :source)
```

It seems it is trying to insert column by column, which is not the behavior I would expect, hence the duplicate row error (two Googles listed as the source). Anyone have any insight into this?

Comment: Check out your backend table, you may have a unique constraint on the 'source' field there, which bombs out the second Google record.

Comment: A unique constraint will not return this error message. Do you have access to the QueryLog to check what was actually sent to TD?

Comment: Turns out I'm stupid - so I was pulling data out of one table using pandas & sqlalchemy, and then trying to run the bulk uploads using just the sqlalchemy library. For whatever reason, sqlalchemy was lower-casing the column names when it generated the insert statement, so only the 'source' column matched, since a bunch of the other columns from the source table are actually capitalized XD